# magento 1.9 There has been an error processing your request

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

"magento 1.9"
my website error many time,

below is my error log.

```
a:4:{i:0;s:48:"SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory";i:1;s:2712:"#0 /home/shop1577/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(55661): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->_connect()
#1 /home/shop1577/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(56141): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->_connect()
#2 /home/shop1577/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(54326): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->_connect()
#3 /home/shop1577/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(55389): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SET NAMES utf8', Array)
#4 /home/shop1577/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(56249): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SET NAMES utf8', Array)
#5 /home/shop1577/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(30320): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('SET NAMES utf8')
#6 /home/shop1577/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(30251): Mage_Core_Model_Resource->_newConnection('pdo_mysql', Object(Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element))
#7 /home/shop1577/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(12259): Mage_Core_Model_Resource->getConnection('core_write')
#8 /home/shop1577/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(12289): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->_getConnection('write')
#9 /home/shop1577/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(12274): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->_getWriteAdapter()
#10 /home/shop1577/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(12299): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->_getReadAdapter()
#11 /home/shop1577/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(32356): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->getReadConnection()
#12 /home/shop1577/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(24241): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract->__construct(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Website))
#13 /home/shop1577/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(24273): Mage_Core_Model_Config->getModelInstance('core_resource/w...', Object(Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Website))
#14 /home/shop1577/public_html/app/Mage.php(491): Mage_Core_Model_Config->getResourceModelInstance('core/website_co...', Object(Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Website))
#15 /home/shop1577/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(5882): Mage::getResourceModel('core/website_co...', Object(Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Website))
#16 /home/shop1577/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(5887): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->getResourceCollection()
#17 /home/shop1577/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(21119): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->getCollection()
#18 /home/shop1577/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(20977): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initStores()
#19 /home/shop1577/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(20860): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initCurrentStore('', 'store')
#20 /home/shop1577/public_html/app/Mage.php(685): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#21 /home/shop1577/public_html/index.php(182): Mage::run('', 'store')
#22 {main}";s:3:"url";s:20:"/irize-1-refill.html";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";}
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

Please disabled the compilation mode and delete the files under includes, except config.php and .htaccess.